# Getting dynamic content from a website through javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, dynamic, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping

I am creating a firefox plugin and using javascript. I am using XMLHttpRequest to get dynamic content from a remote website and storing it into a file to parse it later. But in responseText i am not receiving any dynamic content. After storing information that i got is only the html page not having dynamic content.

code:

```
var res="";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onload = function(){

res=this.responseText;
}   

req.open("GET","www.ebay.com", true);

req.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's can't be done due to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), so you can only request content within the origin domain.

Here are some links may be helpful to you:
[Getting CORS Working](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/)
[Cross-domain Ajax with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

---

Edit:
Since what you want to get from a website is generated by `Ajax`, so it's impossible to get the dynamic content. the `dynamic content` present on the website is after the browser loaded the html page and so the Javascript Event can be triggered to get the `dynamic content` through `Ajax`. You **can** get the html page, but you didn't get the Javascript files. therefor, *Can't* get the dynmic content.

*sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Is there any other way to get remote dynamic content? Ignore that i have to use javascript.

Comment: @user2178385 If you know *python*, there is a lot of methods to get the content from remote server. Since you are creating a firefox plugin and I am not familiar with plugin development, so I can't give you much help.

Comment: I have a doubt. If it is problem with same-origin policy then why i am getting the html content. It should have shown 'access denied' right? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user2178385 I am a little confused, you said you got the html content, what is the `dynamic content` mean?? and some website may allow cross-access. May be you should give a clear definition of `dynamic content`, so others can know what you want.

Comment: by dynamic content i meant to say data which changes on a web page daily that content i am not able to get.

Comment: To be more precise what i am doing is to get the airfare price from a website by javascript which is running in a firefox plugin. I am still not able to get a solution after researching a lot. When the javascript runs what i get is the html but not the flight details. But when i open website in a browser and do a view page source i can see the fare details. So My conclusion is i can get that data via javascript too, but still unable to find a specific solution.

Comment: @user2178385 maybe you should use the `Regex` to get the airfare. if you already get the html data, and you can find the airfare price in the `data`, then you can use `regex` to filter it out.

Comment: that html data i am getting doesn't contains airfare. That is the problem.

Comment: @user2178385 Now I know the problem. you can give me the `page URL` so i can help you find a solution.

Comment: Appreciate your gesture. This is the URL from which i want to retrieve the data : http://www.kayak.com/flights#/MCO-BLR/2013-05-04/2013-06-11

Comment: @user2178385 Well, it's because the airfare price data is not generated by server script but by `javascript`. if you diabled the Javascript on your browser and refresh the page, you won't get the `data`, that's mean, the `data` is retrived by `ajax` after the browser loaded the `HTML & JS scripts`, you use `javascript` can get the `HTML data`, it's impossible to get the `airfare price`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only fetch remote content under your own domain. This is a security issue.  You can use `JSONP`, But for ebay I don't know if there are any json contents available. for more information have a look at this: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-cross-domain-142169

In the case you are using Javascript with a Chrome extension or a Firefox add-on, then you must set permissions in your manifest file to have access to those sites you want.

Comment: Well i am developing a plugin which monitor the airfare of a flight across few websites and whichever website offering the lowest price, The plugin popup a notification on browser. So if i use JSONP and if that site has json content then my problem would be solved?

Comment: That code is able to receive some content but not the price. Other static stuff i am able to receive but not the flight information. Is it the problem with Access-Control-Allow-Origin? Is there no way around to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, but in the case you are using it as an add-on you must set permissions

Comment: To be more precise what i am doing is to get the airfare price from a website by javascript which is running in a firefox plugin. I am still not able to get a solution after researching a lot. When the javascript runs what i get is the html but not the flight details. But when i open website in a browser and do a view page source i can see the fare details. So My conclusion is i can get that data via javascript too, but still unable to find a specific solution.